# How can I get windows properties like with X with Mir?

Tags: window-manager, mir

I started work with Mir and I have a one questions..

How I can work with all application (get title, get active application and etc.) with Mir?

Example in X11 [First link](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s05.html) and [Second link](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s03.html)

Answer (score 1):

as far as i know, there's no api to query application window attributes and shell-specific information at the moment.

there're tons of things to do in mir and unity 8. e.g.shell logic, workspace, window management.
see https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/client-1404-mir-converged workitems.

the EWMH is a spec for X11 which based on the X11 specific notion--Property. i don't think
it'll be reused in either Mir or Wayland.